# How to get id current-logged in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have User class with id, username, and password. And now I want to create a page where I can post some introductions about the user like birthday, about, full name, etc.

But I need to associate this information with id from user table. How can I get current-logged users's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you have your spring-security end working correctly you have three options i think off
one being :

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}
```

The other which i think its cleaner since no casting is required is :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {
     return authentication.getName();
  }
}
```

One other option is :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
     return principal.getName();
  }
```

Here is a good explanation https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-se

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways:

`Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

This gives you the currently logged in user's Principal object for Spring.

What you need to do from there depends.

Principal can be a UserDetails object, or it can be a String, or (unlikely) something else.

If you have an endpoint that you want to inject it into, add it as a parameter to your method and Spring will set it for you:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/my-user-info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String currentUserName(Principal p) {
     String name = p.getName();
     ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is describled in `Spring Security Documentation`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#community-source, Section `Obtaining information about the current user`

Obtaining information about the current user
Inside the SecurityContextHolder we store details of the principal currently interacting with the application. Spring Security uses an Authentication object to represent this information. You won’t normally need to create an Authentication object yourself, but it is fairly common for users to query the Authentication object. You can use the following code block - from anywhere in your application - to obtain the name of the currently authenticated user, for example:

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
String username = principal.toString();
}
```

The object returned by the call to getContext() is an instance of the SecurityContext interface. This is the object that is kept in thread-local storage. As we’ll see below, most authentication mechanisms within Spring Security return an instance of UserDetails as the principal.